# Remove "fixup!" message from `git commit --fixup HEAD`

Tags: git

I often use `git rebase -i HEAD~N` to squash/fixup all my interm commits, or the one I just did, into the former before pushing upstream.

I learned about `git commit --fixup HEAD` which helps me avoid a number of keystrokes.

The issue is it adds "**fixup!**" to the previous commit message, any way to make it stop doing that?

Comment: You mean that after, say, six fixups in a row, the commit messages wind up reading `fixup! fixup! fixup! fixup! fixup! fixup! some commit`? The answer is no, you cannot stop that, it's considered a *feature*.

Comment: Yes exactly. @torek  Minus the *feature* part.

Comment: I don't know why they like adding more prefixes each time. It would make sense if they were worried about rearrangements—that is, given three fixups in a row, we know which must be applied first, which second, and which third—but the order is *also* enforced by the rebase todo file, so this is redundant. And yet, it's clearly done on purpose, and has no control knob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to add the current staged changes to the last commit you probably should use

`git commit --amend --no-edit`

with the `--no-edit` git does not prompt for a new commit message.

As @phd said, fixup is ment to be used with `rebase -i --autosquash`

Answer (score 2):

`git commit --fixup` is not a standalone command, it's a part of series of commands. It's supposed to be used in a scenario like this: you create a number of commits with this *fixup* marks and then run `git rebase --interactive --autosquash`; git automatically combines messages with *fixup* marks.

So no, there is no way to remove these marks other than `git commit --amend`.

Comment: git commit --fixup HEAD doesn't create a new commit. Just applies your current (staged) changes to the last one. Plus prepends the annoying message.

Comment: git rebase -i will remove the marks as well, but I was looking for a nice one liner to avoid it.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It's supposed to be called before `git rebase -i`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you keep using `git commit --fixup HEAD` even after your original commit is no longer HEAD?

First fixup commit:

```
git commit --fixup HEAD
```

Second fixup commit:

```
git commit --fixup HEAD~1
```

Then you don't get more and more "fixup!" tags prepended.